# Running CGI on Jetty

Tags: java, cgi, jetty

I'm starting Jetty from inside the Java program itself. I'm simply trying to get it to point at a cgi-folder that I've placed underneath the package directory (/src/package/cgi-bin)

The problem is that every time I start up the server, it complains "no CGI bin!". Where is the correct location to put your cgi-bin and point at it? This is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // The core Jetty server running on 8080
    Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(8080);

    // Setup CGI routing
    ServletContextHandler context2 = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context2.setContextPath("/");
    context2.setInitParameter("commandPrefix", "perl");

    // Where does this point to? 
    context2.setInitParameter("cgibinResourceBase", "cgi-bin");
    server.setHandler(context2);

    // Add the CGI Servlet
    context2.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new Cgi()), "/cgi");

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

**See [Jetty setInitParameter is NOT initializing any parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216650/jetty-setinitparameter-is-not-initializing-any-parameter) for the answer to this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [Jetty setInitParameter is NOT initializing any parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216650/jetty-setinitparameter-is-not-initializing-any-parameter)

The problem is that I was setting the parameter on the *context*, when I should have been setting it on the `ServletHolder`

Answer (score 1):

In [looking at the code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/CGI.java) it appears that your `setInitParameter` was not set appropriately.  You seem to be doing the right thing although we use XML to configure Jetty and I'm not familiar with doing it in code.

Have you tried to add the servlet *before* setting the handler?  Is it possible that it is called `init` at the wrong time?

```
String tmp = getInitParameter("cgibinResourceBase");
if (tmp == null) {
    tmp = getInitParameter("resourceBase");
    if (tmp == null)
        tmp = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
}

if (tmp == null) {
    Log.warn("CGI: no CGI bin !");
    throw new ServletException();
}
```

No much help but I'll leave this answer up until someone posts a better answer.

Comment: I guess this was the best we could do, but thanks though. It did help me in the right direction, but that method is actually called upon server.start(). I simply do not understand why setInitParameter isn't carrying the information over.

Comment: the source has moved, it is now here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/CGI.java

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not pointing to the correct location for your `cgi-bin`.

```
// Where does this point to? 
context2.setInitParameter("cgibinResourceBase", "cgi-bin");
```

The correct path should be relative to your `WEB-INF` directory, or as a fail-safe, the absolute path on your `file-system`.

In this case, you should use `/src/package/cgi-bin`, assuming that `src` is at the root of your `file-system`. If it is not, you can use something as the following:

```
// The second argument is the absolute path to your cgi-bin
context2.setInitParameter("cgibinResourceBase", "/usr/local/some-more-path/src/package/cgi-bin");
```