# Put mimetex.cgi on jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty, latex, cgi, jetty-9

I try to run the mimetex.cgi on a jetty 9.1.2.
I never use a .cgi file and haven't any knowledge on this topic.

> Now just mv mimetex.cgi to your cgi-bin/ directory, 
>   set permissions as necessary, and you're all done. (John Forkosh)

I don't know where I can't find the `cgi-bin/` directory in the jetty folder structure. But
I found the hint to modify the `jetty.xml` like this:

```
<Call name="addContext">
  <Arg>/cgi-bin/*</Arg>
  <Set name="ResourceBase">/home/jules/www/cgi-bin</Set>
  <Set name="ServingDynamicServlets">TRUE</Set>
  <Call name="addServlet">
    <Arg>Common Gateway Interface</Arg>
    <Arg>/</Arg>
    <Arg>com.mortbay.Servlet.CGI</Arg>
    <Put name="Path">/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin</Put>
  </Call>
</Call>
```

But I don't know which values I should set in Path and ResourceBase exactly.
Sorry for my cluelessness, maybe anyone can help with a simple example.

Regards,
Phil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running CGI on Jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763762/running-cgi-on-jetty)

Comment: thank you for your comment. This issue is no longer in work by me